# Finding reason for reboot RHEL 7

Tags: rhel, kernel, aws

I have RHEL 7 machine running workloads. The machine is provisioned in AWS of instance c5. During workload the process got killed and the machine shutdowns.

I need to analysed why the machine got shutdown.

On analyzing the journalctl logs, we could see the logs after the machine boot.
Analyzing `sar` logs gives no luck.

Is that any other log that could help in analyzing the reason for reboot.